# SSRS change port from 80 server committed a protocol violation

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis, reporting-services, port

I had reporting services running locally, using the default port 80. Today I installed IIS which I believe has caused an issue. I can no longer browse to my local reports or even the report manager screen. I was getting no error, just a total lack of response and a blank page.

Following on from this i took the advice mentioned in this blog:

http://www.seankilleen.com/2012/11/how-to-stop-sql-server-reporting.html

First I tried setting reporting services's port to 81, then 8080. Both times I received the following error message:

**The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine**

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can leave IIS on port 80 and allow my reporting services to function once again on a different port?